# JDBC driver for Oracle 10G XE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have installed Oracle 10G XE. I want to connect to it using JDBC . Which driver should i use for it and from where can i download it ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the machine you have installed the server, Oracle JDBC drivers are in `ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib`. Just put `ojdbc14.jar` on your classpath (`ojdbc14_g.jar` is the same as `ojdbc14.jar`, except that classes were compiled with "javac -g" and contain some tracing information).

**EDIT:** According to [Oracle Database 10g  Release 2 (10.2.0.4) JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_10201.html), `ojdbc14.jar` contains *classes for use with JDK 1.4 and 1.5* (and I don't see why it **wouldn't** work with a JDK 6, some features of JDBC 4.0 won't just be available).

Some newer drivers are available at [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_112010.html) but I don't really see the difference between `ojdbc14.jar` and `ojdbc15.jar` (except that `ojdbc15.jar` requires a JDK 5+): they are both [JDBC 3.0 driver](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_faq.html#02_04) so I think it's just a matter of end of life support for `ojbdc14.jar`. If you want JDBC 4.0 support, you'll need `ojdbc16.jar` though. Have a look at the [Oracle JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_faq.html) if you want more details.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html

You generally want the latest JDBC drivers, they will work with older versions of the database as well. Or, to be on the safe side, match the JDBC version with your DB.

Comment: In fact, the correct version of the driver should be in the Oracle install tree somewhere after the install is completed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this getting started guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25320/getstart.htm) you need the Oracle Express client which [can be found here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/htdocs/102xewinsoft.html)

Comment: You do not need Oracle Express client if you want to use JDBC. There is a pure-Java JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

You want to choose a JDBC driver that matches both your version of Oracle and the JDK you're using.  ojdbc14.jar is for JDK 1.4; there are newer versions for at least JDK 5 that I know of.  I'm not sure if there's a JDBC driver for JDK 6.  Use the best match to your situation that Oracle makes available.