# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ojdbc

I am trying to produce a test webservice in java. I'm facing a problem that when I run my code locally in the main method I get a connection and the code runs normally, but when I try to call the consumer web service, I get the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.7:1521:xe
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:ahmed-HP

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.7:1521:xe
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.ExecuterSoapBindingStub.getInfo(ExecuterSoapBindingStub.java:157)
    at com.CallsWs.main(CallsWs.java:11)
```

Note that am using tomcat

any help please ?

Comment: [JDBC driver for Oracle 10G XE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053584/jdbc-driver-for-oracle-10g-xe) and [SQLException: No suitable Driver Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103369/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcoraclethin-localhost1521-or) might help. It looks like you don't have the Oracle JDBC driver in your classpath when you're running the program.

Comment: tomcat/lib perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853054/classnotfound-exception-when-using-jdbc-for-mysql-on-tomcat-in-eclipse

Comment: Why are you asking such a question?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat doesn't have JDBC Oracle driver installed in tomcat/lib .

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/oem/ucp-jdbc-tomcat-355431.html

might help you setting up this or contact hosting provider

Comment: Please refer to the whitepaper "UCP with Tomcat" (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-tomcat-2265175.pdf) for more details